# Get value from json with non unique key in php

Tags: php

I have a json object as follows. I need to get `val1`. I can do this using the following code if I specify the `non_unique_name` however as the name implied this can change so I am unable to retrieve it.

```
<?php
$json = '{"key": {"non_unique_name": {"val1": true, "val2": flase}}}';
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
print_r( $array );
$location = $array['key'];
echo $location['non_unique_name']['val1'];
?>
```

I have tried to access it using `echo $location[0]['val1'];` however this doesn't work. Would anyone know the correct way to access this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the key value using `key($location)`.

When `key($location)` returns 'non_unique_name', you can use

```
$location[key($location)]['val1'];
```

to get `true` (value of val1 in JSON).

Answer (score 0):

use `array_values` to get the `'non_unique_name'` key values

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($json ),true);
$a =array_values($array['key']);
print_r($a[0]['val1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable `val1` by:

```
$json = '{"key": {"non_unique_name": {"val1": true, "val2": false}}}';
$json_array = json_decode($json);
foreach($json_array as $val)
{
    echo $val->non_unique_name->val1;
}
```